# Give certain character(s) as variables in JavaScripts "replace"-function

Tags: javascript, regex, variables, replace

I'm trying too use JavaScripts "replace"-function to put tags around text given in between certain characters. Example:

```
str.replace(/\_(.*?)\_/gi, '<u>$1</u>');
```

Now this works fine but I want the "_"-characters to be given as a variable.
For example:

```
var und = "_";
str.replace(/\und(.*?)\und/gi, '<u>$1</u>');
```

My question is how can I do that?

Thnx in advance!

Comment: @depperm What are you talking about??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `RegExp` constructor to construct a regex from variable:

```
var und = "_";
var re = new RegExp(und + '(.*?)' + und, "gi");

var repl = str.replace(re, '<u>$1</u>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`new RegExp(pattern, flags)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to build the regular expression from a string.